# Where do I find the grid file "Und_min1x1_egm2008_isw=82_WGS84_TideFree.gz"?

Tags: wgs84, egm2008

I want to download the file `Und_min1x1_egm2008_isw=82_WGS84_TideFree.gz`.

I went to https://earth-info.nga.mil/index.php?dir=wgs84&action=wgs84
and downloaded under Data/Apps -> EGM2008, this file:

https://earth-info.nga.mil/php/download.php?file=egm-08spherical

The readme mentions the file I am looking for called `Und_min1x1_egm2008_isw=82_WGS84_TideFree.gz`. However, after extracting the archive, I can not find the file.

Where do I get the grid file from?

Answer (score 0):

To anyone wondering how to get the mentioned file "Und_min1x1_egm2008_isw=82_WGS84_TideFree.gz", since this file is currently still referenced also in several EPSG definitions, e.g. [EPSG:3859](https://epsg.io/3859) or [EPSG:8037](https://epsg.io/8037).

As far as I can see now, **the file is not available anymore.**

### Alternatives:

Depending on the application you can use this **.gtx-file**:
https://github.com/OSGeo/proj-datumgrid/blob/master/world/egm08_25.gtx

Or you can download a **.tif-file** from [agisoft.com](https://www.agisoft.com/downloads/geoids/) which is based on the file mentioned above, here is a download-link: https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/download.agisoft.com/gtg/us_nga_egm2008_1.tif